# Modular and prime prove

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that $p$ is prime and $p=n^2 +5$ for some natural number $n$, prove that the final digit of $p$ is equal to $1$ or $9$ which is $p=1(mod10)$ or $p=9(mod10)$

What I have to tried so far: in order to get last digit of $p$ be $1$ or $9$, the last digit of $n^2$ must be 4 which gives us $4^2=16$,$6^2=36$ then $16+5=21, 36+5=41$. Similarly last digit of $n^2$ must be $4$ to obtain a p has $9$ as the last digit which is exactly $1(mod10)$ and $9(mod10)$. But those are like listing the special cases, can anyone tell me if I am on the right track or what should I do?

Comment: What final digits can $n^2$ have? (If you don't know, try squaring all the numbers from $1$ to $20$.) Therefore, what final digits can $n^2+5$ have? And what final digits can a prime $p > 5$ have?

Comment: Note that $n$ is even. So the only possible final digits of $n$ are $2,4,6,8$. Compute.